# How to display winners of an election (according to their positions)?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a database where I am trying to display the outcome of an election. 
I would like it to display the winners for of each of the candidate position (in-order) from “PRES” to “COMA”.

I’ve been trying to do it using `MAX` and `ORDER BY FIELD`

```
string sql = "SELECT candidate_name, candidate_surname, candidate_position, MAX(vote_count) 

FROM candidate_list 

ORDER BY FIELD(candidate_position,
'PRES',
'VP', 
'SEC', 
'ASSE', 
'TRE', 
'AUD', 
'BUMA', 
'PRO', 
'COMA')”;
```

> Candidate position with their number of votes

[HERE IS THE CANDIDATE_LIST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwaWz.png)

> Updated Output using subquery

```
SELECT t.candidate_position, t.candidate_photo, t.candidate_surname, t.candidate_name t.vote_count  

FROM candidate_list t

JOIN (SELECT candidate_position, MAX(vote_count) as mxresults

FROM candidate_list

GROUP BY candidate_position) x

ON x.mxresults = t.vote_count and t.candidate_position = x.candidate_position
```

[output using subquery code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8nLl.png)

Comment: Can you post an example of the data you have in `candidate_list`?

Comment: i updated the content thanks

Comment: your query seems right  .. you have error .? . show the error message ... wrong result show you actual result and you expected  result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the winner only you could try using a subquery for max votes

```
select  a.candidate_name
      , a.candidate_surname
      , a.candidate_position
      , b.votes
from candidate_list 
inner join  (
  select candidate_position
      ,  MAX(vote_count)   votes
  from candidate_list 
  ) t on t.candidate_position = a.candidate_position 
           and a.vote_count = t.votes
 ORDER BY FIELD(a.candidate_position, 'PRES','VP', 'SEC', 
   'ASSE', 'TRE', 'AUD', 'BUMA', 'PRO', 'COMA')
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It worked, I just need to know how i could arrange the candidate_position in a specific order. Hope you could help thanks!

Comment: which order you need  for candidate??

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the help